# Get rid of parenthesis in output

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I think this is an easy question for you as i am a beginner on python3.
When printing header of fasta file it contains parenthesis. How can i remove them ??

```
import sys
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO


#define email for entrez login
db           = "nuccore"
Entrez.email = "someone@email.com"

#load accessions from arguments
if len(sys.argv[1:]) > 1:
  accs = sys.argv[1:]
else: #load accesions from stdin  
  accs = [ l.strip() for l in sys.stdin if l.strip() ]
#fetch
sys.stderr.write( "Fetching %s entries from GenBank: %s\n" % (len(accs), ", ".join(accs[:10])))
for i,acc in enumerate(accs):
  try:
    sys.stderr.write( " %9i %s          \r" % (i+1,acc))  
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db=db, rettype="fasta", id=acc)
    seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "fasta")

    if (len(seq_record.seq) > 0):
      header = ">" + seq_record.description + " Len:" , len(seq_record.seq)
      print(header)
      print(seq_record.seq)
  except:
    sys.stderr.write( "Error! Cannot fetch: %s        \n" % acc)


 ./acc2fasta.py 163345 303239
```

It will return

```
(">M69206.1 Bovine MHC class I AW10 mRNA (haplotype AW10), 3' end Len:", 1379)
TCCTGCTGCTCTCGGGGGTCCTGGTCCTGACCGAGACCCGGGCTGGCTCCCACTCGATGAGGTATTTCAGCACCGCCGTGTCCCGGCCCGGCCTCGGGGAGCCCCGGTACCTGGAAGTCGGCTACGTGGACGACACGCAGTTCGTGCGGTTTGACAGCGACGCCCCGAATCCGAGGATGGAGCCGCGGGCGCGGTGGGTGGAGCAGGAGGGGCCGGAGTATTGGGATCGGGAGACGCAAAGGGCCAAGGGCAACGCACAATTTTTCCGAGTGAGCCTGAACAACCTGCGCGGCTACTACAACCAGAGCGAGGCCGGGTCTCACACCCTCCAGTGGATGTCCGGCTGCTACGTGGGGCCGGACGGGCGTCCTCCGCGCGGGTTCATGCAGTTCGGCTACGACGGCAGAGATTACCTCGCCCTGAACGAGGACCTGCGCTCCTGGACCGCGGTGGAGACGATGGCTCAGATCTCCAAACGCAAGATGGAGGCGGCCGGTGAAGCTGAGGTACAGAGGAACTACCTGGAGGGCCGGTGCGTGGAGTGGCTCCGCAGATACCTGGAGAACGGGAAGGACACGCTGCTGCGCGCAGACCCTCCAAAGGCACATGTGACCCGTCACCCGATCTCTGGTCGTGAGGTCACCCTGAGGTGCTGGGCCCTGGGCTTCTACCCTGAAGAGATCTCACTGACCTGGCAGCGCAATGGGGAGGACCAGACCCAGGACATGGAGCTTGTGGAGACCAGGCCTTCAGGGGACGGAAACTTCCAGAAGTGGGCGGCCCTGTTGGTGCCTTCTGGAGAGGAGCAGAAATACACATGCCAAGTGCAGCACGAGGGGCTTCAGGAGCCCCTCACCCTGAAATGGGAACCTCCTCAGCCCTCCTTCCTCACCATGGGCATCATTGTTGGCCTGGTTCTCCTCGTGGTCACTGGAGCTGTGGTGGCTGGAGTTGTGATCTGCATGAAGAAGCGCTCAGGTGAAAAACGAGGGACTTATATCCAGGCTTCAAGCAGTGACAGTGCCCAGGGCTCTGATGTGTCTCTCACGGTTCCTAAAGTGTGAGACACCTGCCTTCGGGGGACTGAGTGATGCTTCATCCCGCTATGTGACATCAGATCCCCGGAACCCCTTTTTCTGCAGCTGCATCTGAATGTGTCAGTGCCCCTATTCGCATAAGTAGGAGTTAGGGAGACTGGCCCACCCATGCCCACTGCTGCCCTTCCCCACTGCCGTCCCTCCCCACCCTGACCTGTGTTCTCTTCCCTGATCCACTGTCCTGTTCCAGCAGAGACGAGGCTGGACCATGTCTATCCCTGTCTTTGCTTTATATGCACTGAAAAATGATATCTTCTTTCCTTATTGAAAATAAAATCTGTC
Error! Cannot fetch: 303239
```

How to get rid of parenthesis in output ??

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo The reason there are brackets is because you're creating a `tuple` by comma separating the description and length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  header = ">" + seq_record.description + " Len:" , len(seq_record.seq)
  print(header)
```

You're printing the representation of the `tuple` by doing so, with commas (expected) but also parentheses (unrequired)

The best way would be to `join` the data instead, so comma is inserted between the string fields, but `tuple` representation is left out:

```
print(",".join(header))
```

In your case it's a little tricker, you have to convert non-string arguments to string (`tuple` representation did the conversion but `join` doesn't):

```
print(",".join([str(x) for x in header]))
```

result:

```
>M69206.1 Bovine MHC class I AW10 mRNA (haplotype AW10), 3' end Len:,1379
```